# Draw the percentage of each class compare to the total amount of each class contain in R

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

I am new to programmation R and I have the problem to display the percentage of each class compare to the total bills of all classes. For example I have data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    time = factor(c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(12.75,14.89, 17.23)
)
```

and I want to draw using `ggplot` and `geom_bar` to display the percentage like this: for class Breakfast the percentage is 12.75/(12.75+14.89+17.23). for Lunch and Dinner I want the same.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be to do some pre-processing of your data to make the plotting easier.  There are methods to do this in-line with `ggplot`, but honestly this is how I would approach the question.

```
# add a column for percent of total bill
dat$bill.perc <- (dat$total_bill/sum(dat$total_bill)) * 100

# example plot with some minimal formatting
ggplot(dat, aes(time, bill.perc)) +
    geom_col(width=0.7, aes(fill=time), show.legend = FALSE) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.